# assign result of function call to variable in oop php

Tags: php, oop

I have made a function for fetching data from a DB. It was working fine. Now I want to do it using OOP, as I am new to OOP I am not getting whats going Wrong. Help me out guys I'm not able to assign the value of function call to variable.

```
class user_functions
    {
        function select_data($sql)
        {
            global $conn;
            $result_final = array();
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);   
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $result_final[] = $row;
            }
            return $this->result_final;     
        }
    }
    $test = new user_functions;
    $sql= "some Query";
    $result =$test->select_data($sql,$conn);
```

Comment: `$result_final` (normal variable) !== `$this->result_final` (property)

Comment: I am trying this $test = new user_functions; $result=$test->select_data($sql,$conn);
                          print_r($result); but its not working.

Comment: change `return $this->result_final; ` to `return $result_final;` and it will work. However, you need to work on your code because it is pretty bad(low quality)

Comment: @Robert                                                                                           $test = new user_functions;                                                              $result =$test->select_data($sql,$conn); but what i want to ask is how this assignment to $result will work ?

Comment: it is local array which will be returned by method by copying value and assiging it to $result outside class scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
class user_functions
{
    function select_data($sql)
    {
        global $conn;
        $result_final = array();
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);   
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $result_final[] = $row;
        }
        return $result_final;     
    }
}
```